# Sticky header and footer with autoscrolling content

Tags: html, angular, css

I'm trying to make a layout where the header and the footer would be sticky at their position, and the content would have a minimum height and shows a scrollbar if the viewport height is too small.

I successfully performed it, on this codepen : 
http://codepen.io/DlafCreative/pen/wzdOEN
inpired from another one.

The problem is that the HTML markup is not convenient with the framework I use (Angular2), as the `<header>` is at the same level that `<main>`, and the `<footer>` is outside `<prop-wrapper>`.

In my app, header should remain the same in all pages, whereas footer should be dynamic. So what I'd like is having `<header>` before `<prop-wrapper>`, and `<footer>` after `<main>`, like this forked codepen : http://codepen.io/DlafCreative/pen/xEAXxy
This way, I could more easily define the content of

Now, I struggle to get the same behavior with that markup. Help would be welcome ! 
Thx a lot :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might help you. So how it works is given below:

1. First of all, remove the browser's default margin using:

   ```
   body {
     margin: 0;
   }
   ```
2. Make your `prop-body` a `flexbox` by using `display: flex`. You will give `flex-direction: column` to make it flex vertically. To fill the whole screen height give `height: 100vh`:

   ```
   prop-body {
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     height: 100vh;
   }
   ```
3. Add `flex: 1` to `prop-wrapper` so that it fills the space between `header` and `footer`.

   This is a shorthand that means:

   a. `flex-grow` is 1
   b. `flex-shrink` is 1

   which means that the height of this flex item will fill the remaining space by growing or shrinking.

See `flex: 1` meaning [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-common).

> flex:  Equivalent to flex:  1 0.
>   Makes the flex item flexible and sets the flex basis to zero,
>   resulting in an item that receives the specified proportion of the
>   free space in the flex container. If all items in the flex container
>   use this pattern, their sizes will be proportional to the specified
>   flex factor.

4. Now you can easily see the layout- we are using some nested flexboxes.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
prop-body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}
prop-body header {
  background: grey;
  padding: 20px;
}
prop-body prop-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: lightblue;
  flex: 1;
}
prop-body prop-wrapper main {
  overflow-y: auto;
  flex: 1;
}
prop-body prop-wrapper main p {
  padding: 50px;
}
footer {
  display: flex;
  background: pink;
  min-height: 50px;
  height: 10vh;
}
footer .footer-content {
  flex: 1;
  background: plum;
}
```

```html
<prop-body>
  <header>Header</header>
  <prop-wrapper>
    <main>
      <p>CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT
        CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT</p>
    </main>
    <footer>
      <div class="footer-content">
        Footer
      </div>
    </footer>
  </prop-wrapper>
</prop-body>
```

Comment: Hi. This seems to make the job :) Thank you very much. Btw, could you provide me a link that explains the "flex" shorthand property, I know it can takes many values : 1, 2, 3, 1 100% etc.. but so far I never really understand how it works.

Comment: added in the explanations... hope things are better now? also could you please upvote if you found it helpful :) Thanks!

Comment: Wonderful. Thanks a lot for the work and explanations, the flex: 1 sounds so much clearer and obvious now.

Comment: For french users like me, this is a good article explaining the flexbox concepts with useful Codepen widgets to illustrate : http://vincent-valentin.name/articles/le-petit-flexbox-illustre. The article is 1 year old now, hope there's no major change since